# See the TestFlight crash log in the Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I have sent my app to some external testers via TestFlight, there is a problem that appears only when you install app from TestFlight and if I install it from Xcode, everything is fine.

So I had to remove my app from my iPhone, and add myself as an external tester to see the crash and see the crash log that stored in the setting/privacy page.

The crash log is not so clear for me, I need that Xcode see my crash in the code line and write the reason.

Is there any way that I can connect my phone (with the TestFlight version of my app installed on it) to my Mac and see the crash log in Xcode?

Answer (score 5):

You should go to Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> Crashes

> However, they’ll be able to see your number of sessions and crashes,
>   the day you installed their app, and the latest installed version.

Or you can use `Sending Crash Information (iOS 13 beta)`

> If you experience a crash while testing a beta app, you’ll see an
>   alert asking if you want to send crash details to the developer and
>   Apple through TestFlight. Developers can opt out of receiving this
>   type of feedback, so this option is only available if the developer
>   has it enabled. When the crash alert displays, tap Share, add any
>   additional comments, and tap Submit.

Read more at [TestFlight docs](https://testflight.apple.com).

Also, I can recommend use [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com) service.