# Xamarin.Forms App crashes on iOS when installed via Testlfight

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, app-store, testflight

Hello fellow developers!
I am developing a Xamarin.Forms App for android and iOS.
It works fine in Debug and Release mode on Android Emulators, Android Devices, iOS Emulators.

But there is a problem with iOS Devices. Directly deploying the Debug/Release Builds to a device works. But when I upload the app to the AppStore and install it via Testflight on my device, it crashes on startup.
From the console I can see following errors:

1. "System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type App.Views.Login"
2. "Default constructor not found for type ColorPicker.iOS.Effects.ColorPickerTouchEffectiOS"

The first one is related to my Login View, which has a default constructor and works fine in debug and release builds.
The second one is related to a nugget package.

My question is:
Why are the default constructors available in Debug and Release but not when i download the app via Testflight? And how can I fix this?

Linking behaviour is set to "Link all".

Comment: Is there a full crash log? It can't be judged based on the two errors you sent.  Is there a complete crash log on the real machine?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't get to the point where a crash alert popos up and there aren't any crash logs generated.

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602330/see-the-testflight-crash-log-in-the-xcode) to see the TestFlight crash log in the Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you use the Link all assemblies option you need to manually preserve the classes in your project and potentially mark out library code that isn't linker safe.

There is a Microsoft document specifically catering to this question : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos

You could set your linker behaviour to **Link SDK assemblies only** temporarily while you manually get ready for a full link.

- Preservin code:
  When you use the linker it can sometimes remove code that you might have called dynamically either using System.Reflection.MemberInfo.Invoke, or by exporting your methods to Objective-C using the [Export] attribute and then invoking the selector manually.
  In those cases, you can instruct the linker to consider either entire classes to be used or individual members to be preserved by applying the [Xamarin.iOS.Foundation.Preserve] attribute either at the class-level or the member-level. Every member that is not statically linked by the application is subject to be removed. This attribute is hence used to mark members that are not statically referenced, but that are still needed by your application.
- Skipping Assemblies
  It is possible to specify assemblies that should be excluded from the linker process, while allowing other assemblies to be linked normally. This is helpful if using [Preserve] on some assemblies is impossible (e.g. 3rd party code) or as a temporary workaround for a bug.

  ```
   --linkskip=NameOfAssemblyToSkipWithoutFileExtension // Single assembly 
   --linkskip=NameOfFirstAssembly --linkskip=NameOfSecondAssembly // Multiple Assemblies
  ```

Hope this helps. Make sure you go through the MS doc for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have taken a look at the ms document you mentioned and switched to Link SDK assemblies only.
The problem is that i can't build now because of some linker errors.
"Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _symbolname. Please verify that all the necassary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in."
The problem is that i don't know the symbols here and how to properly link them.
F.e. symbol "_CheckTokenMembership"
There isn't anythin called CheckTokenMembership in my code/referenced projects/Nugets.

Could you help me please? :/

Comment: Have you tried removing bin and obj once?

Comment: Yes - still the same...